# R - computer vision image matching - nearest neighbour for SURF descriptor

Tags: r, computer-vision, k-means, image-recognition, surf

I am using https://github.com/bnosac/image
and the image.dlib package for image matching.
I am trying to match two objects for similarity using SURF.. Also successfully got feature vector.
But in the nearest neighbour comparison (rflann package), I get varying results.
Do I sum up the abs distances and compare?
Also I am getting varying number of rows of surf points for each image (64 columns are constant)

Attached are reference and candidate images.
Reference should match with c1 ideally. Here's my try.

```
 library(image.dlib)
    f <- "D:\\<path to my ref image>\\ref.bmp"
    f1 <- "D:\\<path to my candidate images>\\c1.bmp"
    f2 <- "D:\\<path to my candidate images>\\c2.bmp"
    f3 <-"D:\\<path to my candidate images>\\c3.bmp"

    surf_blobs <- image_surf(f, max_points = 1000, detection_threshold = 30)

    surf_blobs1 <- image_surf(f1, max_points = 1000, detection_threshold = 30)
    surf_blobs2 <- image_surf(f2, max_points = 1000, detection_threshold = 30)
    surf_blobs3 <- image_surf(f3, max_points = 1000, detection_threshold = 30)


    library(rflann)

    kn1 <- rflann::Neighbour(as.matrix(surf_blobs1$surf),as.matrix(surf_blobs$surf),k = 10, build = "kmeans")
    s1 <- sum(abs(kn1$distances))


    kn2 <- rflann::Neighbour(as.matrix(surf_blobs2$surf),as.matrix(surf_blobs$surf),k = 10, build = "kmeans")
    s2 <- sum(abs(kn2$distances))


    kn3 <- rflann::Neighbour(as.matrix(surf_blobs3$surf),as.matrix(surf_blobs$surf),k = 10, build = "kmeans")
    s3 <- sum(abs(kn3$distances))
```

ref image

[image: Reference image 1]

Candidate images

[image: Candidate image 1]

[image: Candidate image 2]

[image: Candidate image 3]

The links are given below
Reference image

https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3fDJ.png

Candidate images

Candidate image 1: https://image.ibb.co/jL6xNw/c1.png

Candidate image 2: https://image.ibb.co/khhF9b/c2.png

Candidate image 3: https://image.ibb.co/bNTYvG/c3.png

Additional candidates to test robustness:

https://image.ibb.co/mHqyfG/c2.jpg
https://image.ibb.co/de0W0G/c3.jpg

Comment: Please provide the outputs you have right now, and the ones you wish to obtain

Comment: > s1
   [1] 0.7868427
   > s2
   [1] 1.047359
   > s3
   [1] 0.748909

I wish to obtain a very low s1 as compared to s2, s3
Assuming I am doing it correctly